# C language- C90-printing multiple copies of specific shape next to each other

Tags: c, loops, shapes

I have created a program which takes as an input:

a number which determines the shape the user wants to be printed,lets say copies

a number which the determines the 'size' of the shape

and a number which determines how many times the shape will be printed..
What I have tried is a for loop in main() function below each 'if' but  the copies are printed one down another..I also came up with the idea of printing the first line <'copies'> times with the necessary padding but that practice seems to be different for every shape (and yes I cannot implement this logic in my code)...What can I do?

```
/*
 Version 5*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int getchoice(void);
int getsize(void);
void oof(int size,int copies); 
void printrhombus(int size);
void printrighttriangle(int size);
void printisoscelestriangle(int size);
void printspace(void);
void printsymbol(void);
void printnewline(void);
void printrowno(int i);
int getcopies(void);

int main(void)
{
    int choice = 0;
    int size;
    int copies;
    for(; (choice = getchoice()) != -1 ;)
    {
        size = getsize();
        copies = getcopies();

        if(choice == 0)
        {
            oof(size,copies);
        }
        else if(choice == 1)
        {
            printrhombus(size);
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            printrighttriangle(size);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            printisoscelestriangle(size);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int getchoice(void)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Please enter which shape you want to be printed (0-3):\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("Your choice is %d\n",choice);
    return choice;
}

int getsize(void)
{
    int size;
    printf("Please enter the number of rows-the size of your shape:\n");
    scanf("\n%d",&size);
    printf("Your size is %d\n",size);
    return size;
}

void oof(int size,int copies) 
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    for(i = 0; i< size; i++)
    {
        for(l = 0; l<copies; l++)
        {
            for(j = 0;j<i;j++)
            {
               printsymbol();
            }
        }

        for(k =0;k<size;k++)
        {
            if(k == 0 || i == 0 ||  k == size-1 || i == size-1)
            {
                printrowno(i);

            }
            else  printsymbol();
        }
        printnewline();
    }
}

void printrhombus(int size)
{
   int i,j;
   int rows1 = (size/2)+1;
   for(i = 1;i<=rows1;i++)
   {
       for(j = 1;j<=((2*rows1)-1);j++)
       {
           if((j==(rows1+(i-1))) || j==(rows1-(i-1)))
              {
                  printrowno(i);
              }
            else if(j>rows1+i-1)
            {
                printspace();
            }
            else if(j<rows1+i-1 && j!= rows1+1-i)
            {
               printsymbol();
            }
       }
       printnewline();
   }
   for(i = rows1-1;i>=1;i--)
   {
       for(j=1;j<=((2*rows1)-1);j++)
       {
           if((j==(rows1+(i-1))) || j==(rows1-(i-1)))
              {
                  printrowno(size-i+1);
              }
            else if(j>rows1+i-1)
            {
                printspace();
            }
            else if(j<rows1+i-1 && j!= (rows1+1-i))
            {
                printsymbol();
            }
       }
       printnewline();
   }
}

void printrighttriangle(int size)
{
   int rowno,colno;
   for(rowno = 1; rowno<=size; rowno++)
   {
       for(colno = 1; colno<= rowno; colno++)
       {
           if ((colno==1) || (rowno == size) || colno == rowno)
           {
               printrowno(rowno);
           }
           else if(colno>rowno)
           {
              printspace();
           }
           else
           {
               printsymbol();

           }
       }
       printnewline();
   }
}

void printisoscelestriangle(int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 1; i<= size; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1;j<= ((2*size)-1);j++)
        {
            if(j ==(size-(i-1)) ||j == (size+(i-1))|| i == size)
            {
                printrowno(i);
            }
             if (j<size-(i-1))
            {
                printspace();
            }
            if(j>(size-(i-1)) && j<(size +(i-1))&& i!= size)
            {
                printsymbol();
            }
        }
        printnewline();
    }
}

void printspace(void)
{
    printf(" ");
    return;
}

void printsymbol(void)
{
    printf("-");
    return;
}

void printrowno(int i)
{

    printf("%d",i);
}

void printnewline(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int getcopies(void)
{
    int copies;
    printf("Please enter number of copies:\n");
    scanf("\n%d",&copies);
    return copies;
}
```

Comment: "print" to a 2-D array (mirroring the screen), then print the array. ie: `screen[0][0] = '$'; // dollar sign on top left corner`

Comment: If you want to print shapes next to each other, you could print the first line of each shape on one line, then the 2nd line of each shape of the next line, and so on. Your main loop should be the lines, the inner loop should be the shapes.

Comment: Well yes .So what are you saying is let say in 'oof' function erase 'printnewline'  and construct a loop which does exactly what the 2 inner for loops do 'copies-1' times? Or thi would not work?